# Is there anyway to connect my React Route with Node JS redirect?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, passport.js

This may be a simple question, or not even possible. I have a basic user authentication using passport. Depending on success or failure, it redirects to a url. I know how to do this using a view engine such as EJS, where you can set the views to an html from an express route. I am wondering if I can connect a "view" with express to a React Router Route in my front end. Any Suggestions would be helpful. Thanks in advance

```
///Server.js in the backend

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/', 
    failureRedirect: '/login?error=wrong',  <----I need this redirect here***
    failureFlash: true
}))


///Client React Router
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Route path="/" component={App} exact />
        <Route path="/movie" component={Movie} />
        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
        <Route path="/login" component={Login} />
        <Route path='/login?error=wrong' component={Login} /> <---to match this path here.***
    </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: Since you are using the same component, just parse the query params and get the desired result. You can use `this.props.location.search // retruns '?error=wrong'` inside your component. You can split it manually or use `query-string` lib to get the values.

Comment: Would I parse  that inside my router component, or my Login component?

Comment: Login one since you are using it for both success and fail.